# add single line comment in tcl tdom

Tags: tcl, tdom

How to add single line comment or multiline comment using tcl tdom?

For example

```
<book>
<!-- book 1 price -->
<name> abc </name>
<price> 150 </price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing. You can add comments by creating comment nodes and inserting it into the DOM tree, or by inserting from a list descriptor, or by inserting from a script.

```
package require tdom

set doc [dom createDocument book]
set root [$doc documentElement]
$root appendChild [$doc createComment "book 1 price"]
```

If you already have a document and just want to add a comment at the top, you can do this:

```
set doc [dom parse ...]
set root [$doc documentElement]
$root insertBefore [$doc createComment "book 1 price"] [$root firstChild]
```

If you don't have a document and need to create the `name` and `price` elements as well, creating nodes one by one becomes too tedious. Instead one can do this:

```
set doc [dom createDocument book]
set root [$doc documentElement]
$root appendFromList {#comment "book 1 price"}
$root appendFromList {name {} {{#text abc}}}
$root appendFromList {price {} {{#text 150}}}
```

If you want to populate a document from a data structure and possibly add some logic, you'll probably want to use `appendFromScript`, which means you need to define some node commands first.

```
dom createNodeCmd element book
dom createNodeCmd element name
dom createNodeCmd element a
dom createNodeCmd element price
dom createNodeCmd comment c
dom createNodeCmd text t

set doc [dom createDocument books]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set n 0
foreach {nm pr} {
    abc 150
    def 120
    ghi 200
} {
    incr n
    $root appendFromScript {book id $n {
        c "book $n price"
        name {a href "http://what/ever?book=$n" {t $nm}}
        price {t $pr}
    }}
}
```

(Note: in the documentation, the type argument to `createNodeCmd` is supposed to be `elementNode`, `commentNode`, `textNode`, etc. IME it can be abbreviated to one or two letters, e.g. `e` / `t` / `co`. Leaving out the `Node` part seems to be a legible compromise.)

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [tDOM](http:///http:/tdom.github.io)